# Can Firebase be used to connect players online

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android card game.i need to create an online multiplayer mode.Can Firebase connect the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Quoted from [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/):

> Store and sync data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced
> across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app
> goes offline.
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted
> database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every
> connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS,
> Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime
> Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest
> data.

So if the state of the card game is represented in JSON, this JSON can be easily shared among players with firebase. When a player plays a specific card, the JSON is modified and automatically synchronized to other players.

Comment: thank you , it really differs much to me